# Applications - (Registered User Name Visibility)

Tags: macos, applications

How do I hide (not change) the name of the user on a Mac application start up screen. I have a software package that is authorised to all users through a encrypted licence file. The software splash screen displays the name of the IT manager on start up.

I am authorised to use this but would prefer not to display the registered name each time it starts.

Answer (score 4):

There is no generic way to hide such a name as the implementation of such a splash screen differs from app to app.

Displaying the license holder’s is usually part of the protection features of the software. Therefore you’re not likely to find an official way of hiding the name.

Hiding the name is usually something wanted by those that do not have a license and don’t want others to see that. If you’re in that category, contact the vendor to see about transferring the old license or buying (possibly at a discount) another seat or license of the software.